# How can I set a style in `\forestset` which requires delayed calculations with the results of node walks?

Tags: expansion, tikz-trees, tikz-styles, trees, forest

What is the correct way to wrap the specification for the tree below into the `my binomial` style defined in `\forestset` and why?

The following code works fine:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\def\p{.25}
\begin{document}
  \begin{forest}
    before typesetting nodes={
      for tree={
        if level=0{
          content={1},
        }{
          content/.wrap pgfmath arg={#1}{content("!u")*\p},
        },
      }
    },
    [A
      [B
        [D
        ]
        [E
        ]
      ]
      [C
        [F
        ]
        [G
        ]
      ]
    ]
  \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

while the following does not:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{
  my binomial/.style={
    before typesetting nodes={
      for tree={
        if level=0{
          content={1},
        }{
          content/.wrap pgfmath arg={#1}{content("!u")*\p},
        },
      }
    },
  },
}
\def\p{.25}
\begin{document}
  \begin{forest}
    my binomial,
    [A
      [B
        [D
        ]
        [E
        ]
      ]
      [C
        [F
        ]
        [G
        ]
      ]
    ]
  \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Specifically, I get a `Missing number, treated as zero \end{forest}` error. I'm presuming this has something to do with expansion which I know very little about. If possible, I'd like to understand the problem, independently of whether there's a workaround.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Defining a style creates another macro argument layer, so you need to double the `#`, like this:

```
content/.wrap pgfmath arg={##1}{content("!u")*\p},
```

Comment: `\forestset` is not to blame. It is the handler `.style` that introduces another macro argument layer...

Comment: Thank you! I could have sworn that I tried that in my original tree, but I obviously missed something somewhere. However, I didn't know *why* and so this is really helpful apart from making me try this again!

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/237562/.